# can we use Javascript other than in webpages?

Tags: javascript

Can we use Javascript for any other purpose or its sole purpose is to make webpages interactive ? By other purpose i mean, for counting number of words in a file etc

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript (a *language*, technically, ECMAScript) can be used in any place an implementation of it can run .. just like Ruby/Perl/Python/etc can run any place there is an implementation. It just happens to be that modern web-browers *can run JavaScript* defacto, which means it is *very* popular in browsers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are many platforms that can run JavaScript like [GoogleV8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) and [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

This blog post has a lot of information about running JavaScript in back-end: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19613

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Windows has had a JavaScript engine for shell-scripting since IE4.0 came out. It's called the Windows Script Host and is one of three consumers of the Active Scripting engine. The other two users are Internet Explorer (until IE9), and IIS's Active Server Pages (ASP) feature (which is otherwise unrelated to ASP.NET).

There's documentation available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=VS.84).aspx